# Traction boundary condition : Cantilever beam

Tags: beam, bending

Since I don't have that much experience with solid mechanics and stress theory, I am a little confused about my understanding.

My problem is a basic solid mechanics problem of cantilever beam bending.
The beam with rectangular cross-section is of length l, width w and height h. The beam is oriented along negative y-direction. A body force of f Newtons is acting on the free end of the beam in the negative z-direction. See picture for a basic sketch of the setup.
[image]
My goal here is to setup the traction boundary condition on free end. From my reading, I see that the traction BC is setup such as
$\sigma . n = [0,0,-f/a]$, where $\sigma$ is a 3x3 matrix and $n$ is the surface normal vector $[0,-1,0]$ and $a$ is the surface area $b*h$.

putting all in,
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_{xx} \sigma_{xy} \sigma_{xz} \\
\sigma_{yx} \sigma_{yy} \sigma_{yz} \\
\sigma_{zx} \sigma_{zy} \sigma_{zz}
\end{bmatrix} . \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -f/a\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
\begin{equation*}
\sigma_{xy}=0, \sigma_{yy} = 0, -\sigma_{yz} = -f/a
\end{equation*}
I have referred multiple explanations and cannot ascertain if my BC is correct. I find is hard to comprehend that for a downward force only the shear stress $\sigma_{yz}$ is affected and others are zero? Am I right?